# Hibernate or JPA with JSF

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am thinking of developing a new JSF application and have decided to go with managed beans and util classes to handle business logic.

For database integration and handling persistence should i stick to JPA API or use the Hibernate specific one? Which one is better among two.

My application is a mid size application.

Comment: Hibernate is a JPA implementation. Your question is similar to "should I use a car or an Audi"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question was if to go with plain JPA or hibernate.Which would be the right choice considering the size of the application.

Comment: If your question is "should I stick to the JPA API when programming" the answer is "it depends". Please stick to questions where a fact based answer is possible. So "What are the advantages of using EntityManager.find() over Session.get()?" is okay, "Using JPA over Hibernate?" is not.

Comment: There is no "plain JPA". JPA is only a specification. It needs an implementation (a provider). This provider can be Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc.

Comment: @mabi,JB Nizet I understood what i need to do now.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking good way to developing your your JSF Application.

You should go through the JPA. Beacause JPA is good for database integration and easy to handle. It is far better.

Create the HibernateUtil call and provide you persistence init name.

Ex:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    static {
                try {
                     entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("**PersistenceUnitName**");
                     System.out.println("Entity Menager Test.............."+ entityManagerFactory);
                } catch (Throwable ex) {

                    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);

                  }
    }

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
         return entityManagerFactory;
    }

}
```

Persistence unit name is should match to with Persistence.xml file and then crete the Entity classes, DAO and services.

Comment: I find it hilarious that you advocate JPA and go on to name your helper class `HibernateUtil`

Comment: and why on earth he would want to use application managed entity manager ? I get sick every time I see `EntityManagerFactory`